# Can solder sucker tools release lead particles?

Tags: soldering, safety

I have been desoldering a lot in my work. I use those manual spring solder suckers. I noticed that the opposite side of the nozzle ( the plunger, where the thumb goes) is impregnated with solder particles. It ’s not a lot, but it is enough to see them.

I am worried about getting solder particles blown up in my face every time I use the desoldering pump. Is this enough to cause me lead poisoning?

Comment: Could you provide us with a picture of the solder particles?
Also, in these kind of situations (and in soldering in general) as soldering particles are common (whether you use a spring solder sucker or not) you definitely need to have an air ventilator which pulls all the waste away from you.

Comment: If the solder is lead-free then not likely.

Comment: I think it is possible, yes. I don't use the solder sucker all that often but it produces a lot of fine particles inside the sucker chamber and I would not be surprised if some of those particles end up on the outside over time. Wash your hands when you leave the soldering area before you go somewhere else. I try to make a point of always washing my hands thoroughly if I transition from rework to computer work.

Comment: @SolarMike As opposed to getting the even unhealthier RoHS flux particles in your face instead?

Comment: I'm more concerned about sucker particles spread over the work area and over my clothing, where they are transferred elsewhere. Your worry about lead **inside your body** is valid. When you're eating food elsewhere, you're not likely thinking about lead particles falling off your clothing or out of your hair into your food.

Comment: Whenever you handle solder or soldered parts, wash your hands before eating. I have used those things for decades and they have not hmred my brian

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can.  In fact ANY soldering operation using lead-based solder will generate lead particles or vapors that you will be exposed to.

You should do one of two things:

1. Use lead-free solder.
2. If that's not possible, put protective equipment and procedures into place to protect yourself.

The biggest danger is lead on your hands that can later be ingested if it gets into your food and drink.

Adults are less susceptible to the effects of lead but if you are around young children use extra caution as they are very susceptible.  In either case caution will go a long way toward mitigating the danger.

Comment: Lead-free solder is far less healthy for the operator than leaded solder. Using lead-free solder as a health precaution is just plain incorrect advise. All the flux and chemicals in RoHS solder cause allergies, asthma and so on, far worse than leaded solder ever did. Lead isn't healthy either but at least it has the advantage of being very heavy. Vaporized flux has always been the main health problem during soldering, regardless of lead/RoHS.

Comment: Some supporting evidence for your claims would be helpful.

Comment: That's what I was taught during IPC certificate training. I suppose the flux in leaded and lead-free solder are both harmful at various degrees, but since you need higher temperature for lead-free solder, more flux will vaporize. Anyway, the only correct counter-measure no matter the type of solder is to use a fume extractor.

Comment: Use a fan and filter next to the work, Failing that, BREATH OUT during soldering

Comment: It is correct that most fluxes, including the preferred flux for hobby work - the activated rosin flux - will produce nastier volatiles the higher the soldering temperature. I'd say that the primary precautions when doing leaded solder soldering are: 1. Keep your fingers out of mouth, nose and ears (!) until you scrub them thoroughly. 2. Keep the tip temperature optimal and the soldering time short but adequate.

Comment: I don’t choose the solder of the device I work on. I just remove the components.